# Reshape one column to multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups COL1
G1     1
G2     3
G3     5
G1     7
G2     9
G3     11
```

And I would like to take the column `Groups` as multiple unique colums such as :

```
       G1 G2 G3 
  1    1  3  5
  2    7  9  8
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Here is the toy data if it can helps :

```
structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G1", "G2", "G3"), 
    Col1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Where is COL1 coming from?

Comment: oups sorry for the type

Comment: COL2 has values 1 and 7 for G1. Why in the resulting table [COL2,G1] value is only 1? Where do values 7-12  go?

Comment: ok sorry for that, I updated the post with correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea is:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Groups", values_from = "Col1")

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  index    G1    G2    G3
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     3     5
2     2     7     9    11
```

Can drop `index` in the end

Answer (score 4):

After your edits, here's a `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Groups,
              values_from = Col1,
              values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(G1,G2,G3))
```

Output:

```
     G1    G2    G3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     3     5
2     7     9    11
```

Data used:

```
df <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G1", "G2", "G3"), 
    Col1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `unstack` from `base R`

```
unstack(df, Col1 ~ Groups)
  G1 G2 G3
1  1  3  5
2  7  9 11
```